# How to re-add default testing to a rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I joined a rails project where the /test folder has been completely removed. I would like to start writing some tests and I would like to use the test framework that rails comes with (Test::Unit?).

How could I go about re-adding the test framework back into the project?

EDIT: Just would like to add I do not care about tests for already existing functionality. I would like to write my own tests for the functionality I am about to work on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365530/generate-only-tests-from-existing-model-controllers.

Comment: The guides may help you on this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#test and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html you will see the classic generated tests